# "None of the managerParameters resulted in a valid name" exception after installing and configuring FOSUserBundle on a CMF project

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-cmf

I get the following error after installing and configuring FOSUserBundle into a CMF project.

```
ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "None of the managerParameters resulted in a valid name".

in /var/www/****/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterMappingsPass.php line 75
at RegisterMappingsPass->getChainDriverServiceName(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /var/www/****/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterMappingsPass.php line 57
at RegisterMappingsPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /var/www/****/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php line 117
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /var/www/****/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php line 619
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in /var/www/****/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2492
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /var/www/****/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2271
at Kernel->boot() in /var/www/****/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2302
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /var/www/****/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

I have no issues when installing FOSUserBundle the same way into a standard symfony2 project.

Thank you for your help, I have absolutely no idea what the problem might be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a storage driver for your User entities. At this moment FOSUserBundle supports doctrine orm, couchdb and mongodb but not phpcr. You can either define your own mapping (and maybe do a PR on FOSUserBundle to add it) or set up Doctrine ORM to manage users and groups in ORM.

Comment: What is a PR ? Could you be a little bit more specific ?

Comment: sorry, i don't see stack overflow comments. if its still relevant: you can just configure FOSUserBundle for one of the storage systems described in the FOSUserBundle documentation. Or you can do your own mappings as explained in the phpcr-odm documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/

Comment: a PR is short for "Pull Request", which would mean to create a fork of the FOSUserBundle and set things up in there, then push your changes to github and then in the web view go to "pull requests" and click "New pull request". That way, you get feedback on your solution and it will be maintained with the rest of FOSUserBundle.